# Cannot install and import tensorflow_federated in colab

Tags: python, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I want to try a simple federated learning example in python. For it, I need to import tensorflow_federated package.

```py
import tensorflow_federated as tff
```

Here is the stack trace

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-961ae1555cfa> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow_federated as tff

14 frames
/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py in _type_check(arg, msg, is_argument)
    147         return arg
    148     if not callable(arg):
--> 149         raise TypeError(f"{msg} Got {arg!r:.100}.")
    150     return arg
    151 

TypeError: Callable[[arg, ...], result]: each arg must be a type. Got Ellipsis.
```

How should I resolve this error?
BTW, I read in a forum that the problem might be resolved by updating the python version, however it still exists despite I updated it to v3.9
The full stack trace is as follows (I had to submit a screenshot of it was misinterpreted by stackoverflow as some quotes and codes that are not in the right format)
[image]

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @kakigadol I upadated the question and added the full stack trace

Comment: Could you try v3.10? A similar error in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74985672/typeerror-when-importing-tensorflow-federated was resolved with v3.10.