# TypeError when importing tensorflow_federated

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I've been trying to import TensorFlow_federated but have stumbled across an error. After extensively searching the Internet I am yet to find anyone who has encountered the same:

```
import collections
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff

np.random.seed(0)

tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')()
```

The above returns the following, has anyone experienced anything similar:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/metrics/keras_utils.py in <module>
 38     metrics_constructor: Union[MetricConstructor, MetricsConstructor,
 39                                MetricConstructors]
 ---> 40 ) -> Tuple[Callable[[], StateVar], Callable[[StateVar, ...], StateVar],
 41            Callable[[StateVar], Any]]:
 42   """Turn a Keras metric construction method into a tuple of pure functions.

/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py in __getitem__(self, params)
814                                 f" Got {args}")
815             params = (tuple(args), result)
--> 816         return self.__getitem_inner__(params)
817 
818     @_tp_cache

/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py in inner(*args, **kwds)
259         except TypeError:
260             pass  # All real errors (not unhashable args) are raised below.
--> 261         return func(*args, **kwds)
262     return inner
263 

/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py in __getitem_inner__(self, params)
837                 return self.copy_with((_TypingEllipsis, result))
838             msg = "Callable[[arg, ...], result]: each arg must be a type."
--> 839             args = tuple(_type_check(arg, msg) for arg in args)
840             params = args + (result,)
841             return self.copy_with(params)

/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py in <genexpr>(.0)
837                 return self.copy_with((_TypingEllipsis, result))
838             msg = "Callable[[arg, ...], result]: each arg must be a type."
---> 839             args = tuple(_type_check(arg, msg) for arg in args)
840             params = args + (result,)
841             return self.copy_with(params)

/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py in _type_check(arg, msg, is_argument)
147         return arg
148     if not callable(arg):
--> 149         raise TypeError(f"{msg} Got {arg!r:.100}.")
150     return arg
151 

TypeError: Callable[[arg, ...], result]: each arg must be a type. Got Ellipsis.
```

Comment: to me that looks like a bug or incompatible version. The typing package gets updated quite often. Maybe you need to update(or downgrade) your python version or the package. You might find some information on github or can raise an issue there.

Comment: thanks. I solved it in the end by upgrading from python 3.8 to 3.10

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same issue and then after a spending some time, I have got the required solution.

```
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated

!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-model-optimization

!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

%load_ext tensorboard

!pip install tensorflow
!pip install --quiet tensorflow-federated==0.20.0

import pandas as pd
import collections
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_federated as tff

np.random.seed(0)

tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')()
```

The above code is running fine and will be able to solve the problem of Tensorflow federated with Colab.